# Criei um db com o Wamp mas quando clico na pasta para ver meus arquivos php n aparece nada

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, servidor, wamp

No phpmyadmin o db está ok, mas quando clico na pasta que tem os phps aparece: Não é possível acessar esse site

Não foi possível encontrar o endereço DNS do servidor de NomeDaPasta.

Meu wamp está verdinho e funcionando, e os phps estão dentro da pasta dele corretamente entao pq n aparece nada?

Tipo n ta achando o db, alguém saberia dizer pq?

Comment: tenta digitar o endereço completo do arquivo e nao so da pasta em sim ou faz um teste cria uma pasta chamada info dentro coloca um index.php com o cod `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` veja se abre

Comment: fiz mas o problema persiste.

Comment: olha nos logs de error do apache que o seu wamp fornece e cola os ultimos logs aqui por favor.

Comment: Gorick X, ficou um pouco confuso o questionamento. Pelo que entendi você tem o Wamp rodando OK, criou o BD e as tabelas OK, quando acessa o servidor via http e clica na pasta do seu projeto ele não encontra ?
Se for isso tem uma configuração do www que deve ser realizada, porém espero que outra pessoa lhe ajude, porém o endereço `http://servidor/nomedoprojeto/index.php` tem que funcionar.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido alterando o arquivo index.php do wamp vlw gente